# Update query with date conversion giving problems

Tags: sql-server

I've written a query to try and update the MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE field (datetime, null) with the date from the EVENTID field (datetime, null) + 180 day's.
I'm just at the beginning of using SQL and a bit stuck on how to solve the problem.
The error I get is: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

my query looks lik this at the moment can someone help me out here?

```
UPDATE UDStay SET "MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE" = "EVENTARRIVED" < CONVERT (DATETIME(8), DATEADD (DAY, +180, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 112) + '0000')
WHERE CONTRACT = 'sde' AND "EVENTDEPARTED" IS NULL AND "EVENTCURRENT" = 'ARRIVED'
GO
```

Comment: What is "EVENTARRIVED" ? Why have you put double quotes for "MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE". Remove the double quotes. You also need to removed double quotes around "EVENTCURRENT"

Comment: ... "EVENTARRIVED" < CONVERT ... I think here you need "EVENTARRIVED" + CONVERT in case we are talking about concatenation. Otherwise, is not clear what operations are you trying to do.

Comment: @Daniel But column "MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE" is datetime, so how can we put string in there? Did i understood wrong?

Comment: sorry but you have to explain more, EVENTARRIVED is a field ? "EVENTCURRENT" = 'ARRIVED' !!

Comment: What are your doing with "<" ? What is logic you want while updating

Comment: @AshReva - yes, now that I read the question more carefully, I think I got it. @S Berghout if you want "MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE field (datetime, null) with the date from the EVENTID field (datetime, null) + 180 day's." - you need MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE = DATEADD(DAY, 180, EVENTID). But in your script you mention EVENTARRIVED. Are we to assume that EVENTARRIVED is in fact EVENTID (or the other way around :) ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question you can use below query.

```
UPDATE UDStay SET MAINTAINANCESCHEDULE =  DATEADD(day,180,EVENTID)
WHERE CONTRACT = 'sde' AND EVENTDEPARTED IS NULL AND EVENTCURRENT = 'ARRIVED'

GO
```

I have ignored condition "EVENTARRIVED" <" from your query. As you said in your question you need to add 180 days to column EVENTID then this query will work.

Please let me know if this is what you need.